# Comment, Approve, Request Changes in Gihtub Pull Requests

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

Last week Gihtub introduced the Reviews functionality for Pull Requests. It was announced in the [Github Blog](http://http:https://github.com/blog/2256-a-whole-new-github-universe-announcing-new-tools-forums-and-features//). It seems to be very useful, except I am unable to find the options for requesting changes, commenting or approving changes in a Pull Request Review. I am using it for a project I am collaborating on with a friend on a private Gihtub repository owned by him.

When hitting the Review button on the open Pull Request, I can only see a textbox to comment and a button to publish the comment as you can see in the following image.

[image: Review Screenshot]

[The video tutorial on reviews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HW0RPaJqm4g&feature=youtu.be) shows some Radio Buttons which should show up under the textbox in my screenshot, except in my case, they don't.

Before trying this feature out, we had no open Pull Requests nor unmerged branches, so the PR was opened *after* this functionality was added to Github. I should also note that although my friend is the repository owner, I am listed as a collaborator on the repo, so I am supposed to have full Read/Write access on it.

Does anyone know if the feature should be somehow enabled in repository settings or if permissions should be added for users to be able to Approve or Request changes on a PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution! Turns out I was trying to approve or request changes on a PR I had opened myself. Code Review is supposed to be a collaborative effort and only someone else should **approve** or **request changes** on your code.

Any other collaborator on the repo who did not open the PR will be able to see the Approve/Comment/Request Changes radio buttons. Silly of me...